# QString parsing items from a list

Tags: c++, string, qt

I have a `QString` formatted like this: `"Test %1 and test %2"`.
I have a separate `QVariantList` variable. Now I would like to create a new `QString` and parse all of the `%` items with the items in my `QVariantList` in the list order. Is there any way to do that in Qt using the `QString` object?

I am hoping for not having to do a single `arg()` call recursively by hand, since that would be very inefficient.

EDIT: for instance:
My `QVariantList` consists of 2 items: 10 (int) and 3.14 (double). The end string should look as follows:

`"Test %1 and test %2"` becomes `"Test 10 and test 3.14"`.
By hand it would be done like this:

```
QString str = "Test %1 and test %2";
QVariantList vl { 10, 3.14 };
QString newStr = QString(str).arg(vl[0].toString()).arg(vl[1].toString());
```

Comment: Could you explain in details, what "parse all of the % items with the items in my QVariantList in the list order." means?

Comment: ...please post and example of what you need to do

Comment: 1) Do you *have* to use QVariant or can you compensate with another container? 2) Have reached a level of efficiency in your program in which the only thing left for you to optimise is the `.arg()` call? 3) How much impact in efficiency does calling `.arg()` have in your program?

Comment: Yes, QVariant is preferable. The reason for not wanting to use `arg()` is that the string would have to be changed after each arg call (the indexes), since there is no method like `arg(QStringList)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve this problem in the following way:

```
QString str = "Test %1 and test %2";
QVariantList vl{ 10, 3.14 };

QString newStr = str;
// Assume that the QVariantList's size corresponds to the number of placeholder.
for (const auto &v : vl) {
    newStr = newStr.arg(v.toString());
}
```

Comment: I am not sure this would work, since after the first call, the second `%x` chunk of text will not become `%1`. Thats the problem with `arg()`. You would have to go through the string again and decrement all indexes by one each time.

Comment: @Bremen, the placeholder value is not necessarily should start from 1. For example: `auto str = QString{"%66"}.arg("foo");` will still give you a `"foo"`. You think, this solution will not work without even trying it. OK.

Comment: In this example this will not work, I have tested it. Assuming the string `"Test %1 and test %2"`, After first run the string becomes `"Test 12 and test %2"` and after second one it becomes `"Test 12 and test "`

Comment: Really? After the first iteration `newStr` is `"Test 10 and test %2"`, after the second one it's `"Test 10 and test 3.14"`. I don't know where 12 comes from.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 10, not 12. But even though the second iteration doesnt translate the second value. Does this code work for you as you describe?

Comment: Yes, it does. Otherwise I wouldn't post it. Maybe I use older version of Qt (4.8) and it doesn't work with Qt 5.x? Update: it's the same with Qt5.14.

Comment: @Bremen Oops, posted duplicate answer. Deleted it now. This works fine. `arg()` does not care whether or not the lowest `%` tag is 1. Every time `arg()` is called, the `%N` with the lowest value of N will be substituted.

Comment: You are right, there was an error in my own example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `.replace()`? I am not sure if this is more efficient than the recursive `.arg()` though. You need to profile it to be sure.

```
QString str = "Test %1 and test %2";
QVariantList vl { 10, 3.14 };

QString newStr = str;
for (int i=0; i<vl.size(); ++i)
{
    QString idx = "%" + QString::number(i+1);
    newStr.replace(idx,vl[i].toString());
}
std::cout<< newStr.toStdString() <<std::endl;
```

Result:

```
Test 10 and test 3.14
```

Comment: Yes, I am starting to think that this is the only option and `arg()` will not work.